# Need to compile a project to .net 3.5 sp1 in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I'm using a cms (mojoportal) and want to install it on a webserver, this webserver has .net 3.5 sp1 installed (a requirement for it to run), and my pc that i compile the project also has 3.5 sp1 (im using windows 7, it comes with 3.5 sp1)

Though I'm getting an error that i know only comes up when the cms is running on 3.5. I believe its because its being compiled on my local machine under just 3.5. Is there a way to compile my project and target 3.5 sp1 specifically.

When you click on the projects properties in visual studio it doesnt show the service packs option.

The error is

Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase' from assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

and i know i have no ToolkitScriptManager in my solution (a fix i read was to change it to asp:ScriptManager)

Thanks in advance

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Your machine sounds messed up, this should work.  Navigate to C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 and look at the properties of the DLL.  The file version on mine is 3.5.30729.4926, modify date 6/10/2009.  Copying the file from another machine is the Q&D fix, reinstalling .NET would be wise.